# how to make a loop on image from 100 to 199 only?

Tags: batch-file

I have this batch file

```
     for %%f in (image1*.jpg) do {
     code here.. 
     }
```

my problem is in 'image*1' its getting images that from 100 to 199 and 1000 to 1999.

Iwant to my loop to get image only from 100 to 199 and  another loop get image from 1000 to 1099

how to do that?

Comment: Use a counting loop `for /l %%c in (100,1,199) Do (echo image%%c.jpg)`

Comment: but i am looping on images not numbers this will considers the images ?

Comment: If the numbers are without gaps, what is the difference? If there are gaps insert an `If exist "image%%c.jpg" whatever`

Comment: Don't guess the syntax, read the documentation (type `for /?` into a command prompt window); you won't find any braces `{}` in the help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /l %%c in (100,1,199) Do If exist image%%c.jpg (
code here...
)
```

A different approach:

```
For /f "delims=" %%f in (
  'Dir /B/A-D image1*.jpg ^|findstr /i "^image1[0-9][0-9]\.jpg$"'
) Do (
code here...
)
```

The findstr with the RegEx will make shure the number starting with 1 has 3 places. For 1000 to 1999 add one more time `[0-9]`